# Cellphone carriers in Europe

Tags: europe, france, cellphones, roaming

I am planning to move to France and I am a bit curious, how do cellular carriers/networks operate in the European Union? If I have a mobile from Orange, will it stop working once I leave France? Is it like International Roaming here in the US, where you pay through the nose? How does it work?

Comment: To the person who voted to close the question: It's essentially about traveling while being based in France, thus fully on topic.

Comment: There seems to be an identical question over on [Expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/mobile-carriers-in-france-and-how-they-work-across-the-eu)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is also asked on expat.se

Comment: I was about to suggest closing the expat one, but it seems to have been better received than this one. It's odd because it really seems like a travel question, with no expat aspect to it.

Comment: @Relaxed Visiting France for a short while = fully on topic here. However, the question (as written) is about moving to France full time, and wondering about long term mobile contracts, and hence might (though only might) be better for Expats.SE. Well, either that, or perhaps the version here might want wording tweaks to distinguish it if not

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes but Jessica is in fact asking about visiting other countries and not about visiting France (whether for a short while or not). She is not asking about the best mobile operator in France for domestic use nor about calling back home as an expat, it's entirely about travel. A French citizen who never left France and wants to go abroad for the first time could ask almost the same question.

Comment: @Relaxed She's asking how roaming in Europe works, which most people living in Europe vaguely know due to all the recent press about the recent price drops on European roaming. I can see how a slightly differently worded version would be on topic here, so maybe this one should just be edited

Comment: @Gagravarr But what would be the point? The question itself would remain the same and is already fully on-topic!

Answer (score 1):

Using a phone outside of France is easy, usually you need to activate roaming once, for free. If you stay within the EU, it's still international roaming but prices are regulated and going down constantly (there is a plan to forbid roaming fees entirely by 2016 but it's not been voted yet). Placing and receiving voice calls and SMS has become quite cheap, data is still a bit expensive (although you can sometimes buy cheaper data bundles). Obviously, you'll have to decide for yourself if [those prices are affordable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Commission_roaming_regulations) to you.

Operators in some European countries offer good deals for roaming outside the EU (which is not regulated) but I don't know any in France. Using your French phone/SIM card back in the US could therefore be expensive.

Note that in France, unlike some other European countries, you can get cheap unlimited international calls to many countries on your landline. Nearly everybody I know has a “triple play” (TV + phone + Internet) or “quadruple play” (same plus mobile) subscription  that includes this (not your question but I guess it might come in handy).

Answer (score 1):

Within the EU there are (still) roaming fees. However, you might check with your provider whether there are any special deals which can lower these fees (such as for calls from France to another country, as well as for calling France from another country.

It may, however, be worthwhile to get a prepaid SIM card for the other country you visit, maybe together with a simple phone.

Comment: Depends on your mobile provider - some mobile plans (eg 3) have free roaming to certain EU countries (+others), while others offer free roaming to all of the EU on their more expensive plans, and yet others offer "free" roaming for a daily fee. Depends a huge amount on who you're with

Comment: and of course roaming charges are regulated by the EU (for whatever reason) to the point where it's almost uneconomical for EU carriers to offer roaming at all.